# In what sense is cotorsion dual to torsion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, torsion-groups

An $R$-module $M$ is called *torsion* if for every $m \in M$, there exists a non-zero divisor $r \in R$ s.t. $rm = 0$. If we let $S$ be the multiplicative system of non-zero divisors of $R$, we get that $M$ is torsion iff

$$ \operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M, R_S/R) = M $$

A module $M$ is called *cotorsion* if

$$ \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(F, M) = 0$$

for every flat $R$ module $F$.

In what sense are these two definitions dual? I see that one uses Tor while the other uses Ext, but apart from that, there are some asymmetries: one asks that Tor = $M$, while the other asks that Ext = $0$. Furthermore, one looks at $R_S/R$, while the other looks at *any* flat module $F$. Can the definitions be rephrased such that the duality works out nicely?

Comment: Probably simpler: $M$ is torsion iff $\operatorname{Hom}(M,I)=0$ for all injective $I$, dualising to $M$ is cotorsion iff $\operatorname{Hom}(P,M)=0$ for all projective $P$.

Comment: @user10354138 That would be what I was looking for. Do you have a proof or reference that these conditions are equivalent to the ones in my question?